# Executing MySQL queries on PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, postgresql, express

I have an Express(Node.js) app which uses MySQL queries.

I do not have a good MySQL hosting, but only PostgreSQL hosting. So, I want to use PostgreSQL.

I do not want to change the code as it is very large.

Is there any way I can edit the db connection file only, in such a way that the things work correctly?

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL syntax differs in details extremely - I doubt that the queries which uses any MySQL-specific constructions will work with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Actually, there are some tools(including online APIs)  which try to do this. I have tried them, but the results are not good. So, I was asking if someone would know a better solution.